# Holomorphic vector fields on compact complex manifolds with trivial canonical bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, calabi-yau

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold whose canonical bundle $K_M$ is holomorphically trivial. Is it possible for $M$ to admit a non-zero holomorphic vector field with zeroes? Equivalently, using a holomorphic volume form, is it possible for $M$ to have a non-zero holomorphic $(n-1)$-form with zeroes? (Here $n$ is the complex dimension of $M$) Any example of this would be much appreciated.

I do know that the answer is negative in case $M$ is in addition Kähler. For then, if $g$ is a Ricci flat metric provided by the Calabi-Yau theorem, holomorphic differentials are automatically parallel with respect to $g$. In particular it will be identically zero if it vanishes somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is no when $n=2$, by a result of Carrell-Howard-Kosniowski, see here http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01431490. I don't know of any example in higher dimensions, but my feeling is that such examples do exist.